# Style sidebar for a custom page template exclusively

Tags: wordpress

Please assist. I have followed a tutorial to create a custom template with a sidebar. The sidebar has been implemented successfully and the page template is called "Custom page Template Wizard". The issue I am having is getting the sidebar to appear left and content on the right. The theme I am using is Ultra7

The issue I am having lies within this test page:
https://devtest2017.aquatiere.co.uk/product-filter-wizard/

The desired layout is not showing up. Does this require css?

This is custom_page.php coding:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Custom Page Template Wizard
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

      <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'wizard-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'wizard-sidebar' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is my custom sidebar template coding (sidebar-wizard.php):

```
<div id="sidebar">
   <ul>
      <?php
      if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('wizard-sidebar') ) :
      endif; ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

AND I have added this code to my themes functions.php file:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Wizard Layout Page',
'id' => 'wizard-sidebar',
'description' => 'Appears as the sidebar on the custom wizard page',
'before_widget' => '<div style="height: 280px"></div><li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</li>',
'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
}
```

This is what the page looks like at present:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! Bit of custom css should sort you right out. Float one item left, the other item right and make sure their combined widths don't surpass that of their parents width. Try popping something like this into your styles.css and see how hour get on. You'll probably have to use different rules to make it mobile responsive. Best of Luck!

```
#main .row div {
    width: 1000px;
    float: right;
}
li#categories-3 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you for your response. I am having another issue whereby the main content is not displaying on the right hand side. Any advise regarding this?

Comment: Hi @Bradley! Did you get your new issue sorted? I had a look at your test link and can't really see what's going on.

Comment: Hey Derek, I made some progress but reverted. Now I need to customize the Woo Commerce shop page which does not allow custom templates easily: https://devtest2017.aquatiere.co.uk/product-filter-wizard/

Comment: @Bradley So what exactly do you need to do? If you want to target elements  on the woocommerce page using css you should be able to add rules using the 'woocommerce' class that's added to the body tag.